# Capturing blinking color in selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

There is a blinking color block in a webpage and i want to capture the color of it.
the block is blinking in yellow. So while running i am getting the CSS background some time as yellow and some time as blank as the block is blinking .
I want to write a code so that it navigate to that block by xpath, fetch the color and wait for 5 sec till yellow color comes in and capture the yellow color only.
How to achieve this .

Comment: the question is not clear. please share relevant HTML code for the element, the code you tried etc.

Comment: The most important piece of information is missing: how is the background blinking. Is it a CSS animation, a transition, an HTML marquee, an animated GIF, a video etc?